# RestKit loadObjects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, restkit

iam using restKit, to send and receive data from server... iam getting back

```
{
    "request":"globalUpdate",
    "updateRevision":2,
    "updatedObjects":{
        "users":[
            {
                id:"someid1",
                name:"somename"
            },
            {
                id:"someid2",
                name:"somename2",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**i want to use**

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:nil usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader * loader){)];
```

**to load only objects inside `updatedObjects` into CoreData and `request`, `updateRevision` into NSDictionary**

so in

```
loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {    

}
```

the first object is the Dictionary and the later one are CoreData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the matter of your choice which object you use for the coredata and which for your own purpose. RKObjectLoader also provides onDidLoadResponse block which has a reference to the response which you could use for your own use.

```
[myobjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.mappingProvider = [RKObjectMappingProvider mappingProviderUsingBlock:^(RKObjectMappingProvider *provider) {
            [provider setObjectMapping:[MyClass mapping] forKeyPath:@"updatedObjects"];
            loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){

            };
            loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
               // NSData * data  = [response data];
                id object = [response parsedBody:nil];
               // now parse the data yourself which will give you
               // the entire json in NSData for and parse it,
               // extract the component you need
            };
            loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error){

            };
        }];
    }];
```